# How to copy local Membership and Role database to remote MS SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I have made a MVC application that uses the built-in ASP.NET login functions. It works perfectly on my local machine. I have bought a webhosting service, because i want to publish my website to the internet.

How do i copy the membership and role database / tables to my new MS SQL Database and make it work with my current project?

In my Web.config i have:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

notice that

```
Instance=true
```

This means that SQL Server Express will open the aspnetdb.mdf file, creating it on the fly first if needed.

When i try to login on my website i get the following error:

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `aspnet_regsql` located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. Just point it to your remote sql server and it should take care of the rest.

You will also need to edit your connection string for application services to the one for your remote sql server.